# Ho w to fetch the user information after successful user login in SAML OKTA

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml, okta, userinfo

I am trying to integrate OKTA SSO into my spring boot application using SAML,
When I try to get the user information after successful login I am getting a lot of user information, which looks like garbage value, I am not able to parse it and fetch the user name.

It would be a great help if someone could share proper API developer documentation which I can refer to or can someone help me to understand how can I read the user response and parse it and fetch the user name. All I want is after successful Okta Login I want to get the logged-in user's user name.

at present, I am using the following code which gives me around two pages of junk data.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public Authentication authenticate1(Authentication authentication){
        ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken token = (ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        System.out.println("hiiii"+token+"nnn"+token.getPrincipal());
        return token;
    }
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.extensions/spring-security-saml-dsl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: i believe that is JWT token you need to parse that and get user details  check this for more info https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/31/jwts-with-java

Comment: I will remove JWT auth from the application @silentsudo, I want to just fetch the user name from SAML response any idea how we can fetch that